# refresh the dom manualy in browser console

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, browser

I have a commponent:

```
const bgc = {backgroundColor: 'red'}

let flag = true

class HelloWorld extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="box" style={{backgroundColor: flag ? "skyblue" : "black"}}>box</div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

you see the component's div background-color is changed by variable `flag`, I can control the value of it.

[image]

you know the HTML DOM would not change accordingly.
so, is there any command can refresh the DOM manually in console?

Comment: Use the react devtools

Answer (score 0):

You need to use 'useState' hook

const [flag, setFlag] = useState(true);